# Is it possible to have a convex unbiased function according to Jensen's?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So Jensen's equality states that if a function is convex, then it is not unbiased. Does that mean all convex functions are biased?

Comment: what do you mean by 'unbiased function'?

Comment: Like trying to determine an estimator is unbiased. Sorry I didn't specify!

Comment: I think a better way to phrase this might be "can there be a strictly convex function $f$ and a non-trivial random variable $X$ such that $f(E[X]) = E[f(X)]$?"

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing bias (property of an estimator) with expectation (property of a random variable).

Let $f$ be a convex function and $X$ be a random variable with expectation $E[X]$.

**What is Bias?**

Bias is a property of an *estimator*. Neither $f(X)$ nor $X$ are *estimators* since we haven't been told what they are supposed to be estimating (let's call that the *estimand*).

However, if we define $\hat{\mu} := \frac{\sum_1^N x_i}{N}$ as an estimator for $E[X]$ (the estimand), then we can talk about the bias of $\hat{\mu}$ relative to $E[X]$ (in this case it's zero as long as $E[X]$ exists).

**What does Jensen's Inequality Really Tell Us?**

Jensen's inequality simply says that $f(E[X])\leq E[f(X)]$ when $f$ is convex.

So, what this means is that if we define the estimator $\hat{\gamma} := f(\hat{\mu})$ for the *estimand* $E[f(X)]$, then indeed Jensen's Inequality suggests that $\hat{\gamma}$ might be a biased (low) estimator of $E[f(X)]$.

However, what Jensen's Inequality really says is that $\hat{\gamma}$ is an *inconsistent* estimator of $E[f(X)]$ in the sense that $\hat{\gamma}$ will not converge to $E[f(X)]$ as $n\to \infty$.

The problem with directly applying Jensen's inequality is that it assumes you *know* $E[X]$. We are actually estimating it so $\hat{\mu} \neq E[X]$ (since $\hat{\mu}$ is a random variable). What we really want to know is if $E[f(\hat{\mu})] \leq E[f(X)]$, which is not strictly addressed by Jensen's Inequality except in the limit as $n\to\infty$.

However, all of this is different from your statement: The bias of a function is not defined. You need to define an *estimator* and its *estimand* in order for the concept of bias to apply.